# How get ID of modern Site Features

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, features, site-design

I am using site designs to create new site collections attached to a hub site with the appropriate features enabled, now I seem to have hit a wall between classic and modern features. I have an action to activate features such as Project Functionality.

Example:

```
{
    "verb": "activateSPFeature",
    "featureId":"e2f2bb18-891d-4812-97df-c265afdba297"
}
```

I would like to now remove some features, Specifically the "Site Pages" feature to stop the end-user from creating site pages on a particular set of site collections. However, I do not seem to be able to find the GUID of the "Site Pages" or the "Mobile Browser View" Feature.

[image: Site Pages Feature]

Does anybody know how I can find this?

I have tried to use the PnP `cmdlet` however this only provides me with classic features, `cmdlet` used:

`Get-PnPFeature`

Any help would be appreciated - It seems to me there is a missing link connection to be able to pull the properties of these features.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> You can prevent a web from using the "modern" page experience by disabling the web scoped feature with ID **B6917CB1-93A0-4B97-A84D-7CF49975D4EC** (name = "Site Pages"). To re-enable the "modern" page experience at the web level, you need to activate the feature again.
>
> **Note**:
>
> When you disable the feature, you can no longer create new "modern" pages, but the already created pages stay working using the "modern" user experience.

**Source**: [Web level configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#web-level-configuration).

If you want to completely disable the "modern" experience, it's best to use the tenant setting for this. Go to your tenant admin center (for example, contoso-admin.sharepoint.com), go to Settings, and select the "classic" experience.

[image]

**Source**: [Tenant level configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#tenant-level-configuration).

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Thanks for the reply, its not disabling the modern experience I am trying to achieve, removing the 'Site Pages' Feature, will remove the ability for end users to create new pages. is this the feature that the above ID relates too?

Comment: Yes, Check the note section if you disable the feature then user cannot create modern pages in your site.